# Puphpet Vagrant box | php cannot access rvm gems

Tags: php, ruby, apache, rvm, vagrant

**I know this comes down to the correct env values not being available for php at runtime.**

1. As the vagrant user via ssh I can run this script via cli and get all the correct output.
2. As the vagrant user if I run **evn | grep rvm** I get a crap ton of entries.
3. I want these same entries to be available to php at runtime.
4. I have tried to run the server as the vagrant user but that still does not get the correct gem.

Here is my test script

```
// Vagrant x64 Debian Wheezy
// Outputs lots of crap
echo passthru('ls -al /var/www/websites/');

// I get nothing with these
echo passthru('compass');
echo passthru('/usr/local/bin/compass');
// the gem actually exists here.
// But I still get nothing
echo passthru('/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/compass');
// Permissions on the file are currently 777 to make sure the is not the problem
// If I execute "compass" via ssh I get the normal output

// If I add this before the script, my output works
putenv('PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin:/usr/bin');
```